# Swift get data from firebase realtime database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner in swift app development and I want to get username based on the email from a firebase realtime database, but it keeps saying that the username is nil even though there do exist a username under the correct email. Could anyone help me with that? Thank you a lot!

This is the getUsername function, I tried printing some values, but nothing is printed:

```
public func getUsername(forEmail email: String) -> String? {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    var foundUsername: String?
    
    databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let topLevelDict = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: String]] {
            print("Top-level dictionary: \(topLevelDict)")
            for (key, value) in topLevelDict {
                           if let username = value["username"] {
                               print("Email: \(key), Username: \(username)")
                           }
                       }
            for (key, value) in topLevelDict {
                print(key)
                if email == key {
                    if let username = value["username"] {
                        foundUsername = username 
                    }
                    print("!!"+(foundUsername ?? "not")!)
                    break // Exit the loop after finding the email
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return foundUsername
}
```

This is what the database looks like:
[firebase realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtNTn.png)

Comment: You are returning `foundUsername` from the function before the call to Firebase has completed. See the linked question above for solutions.